# Transform response with GraphQL and NestJS

Tags: node.js, graphql, nestjs

**Problem**

I'm trying to use NestJS [Serialization](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) to transform an output of my GraphQL mutation:

```
@Mutation('myMutation')
  @UseGuards(GqlAuthGuard)
  async myMutation(
    @Args('input') input: MyInput,
  ): Promise<MyOutputDecorated> {
    return await this.myService.execute({
      ...input
    });
  }
```

`MyOutputDecorated` is a class that inherits from `MyOutput`, I did this because my code is Schema first, it's a recommended approach from the docs:

```
export class MyOutputDecorated extends MyOutput {
  @Transform((value) => {
    console.log('transforming value', value);
    return maskField(value.value)
  })
  FieldIWantToTransform: string;
}
```

```
export class MyOutput {
  ...
  FieldIWantToTransform: string;
  ...
}
```

> `myService.execute` also returns `MyOutputDecorated`

Also, I used globalInterceptors:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useWebSocketAdapter(new SocketAdapter(app));
  const httpAdapter = app.getHttpAdapter();

  app.useGlobalFilters(new CaptureAllExceptionsFilter(httpAdapter));
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }));
  app.useGlobalInterceptors(new ClassSerializerInterceptor(app.get(Reflector)));

  await app.listen(3000);
}
```

But for some reason, my field does not get transformed, the console.log doesn't happen, so the code is not executing.

Does anyone have any idea about what is happening here?

Comment: My bet is that your resolver is decorated with `@Resolver(() => MyOutput)` so GraphQL has no means of knowing that you're returning a `MyOutputDecorated`. If I'm correct then `@Mutation(() => MyOutputDecorated)` would fix the problem.

Comment: please provide your resolver as well